# generate html coding from javascript in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net, xhtml

I'm doing html to well formed html in c#, all the process completed except javascript, please help to achive this:

my html has javascript for ex:

```
<html><body><b>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
 var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
 var addy21908 = 'fr&#97;nch&#97;n' + '&#64;';
 addy21908 = addy21908 + 'sph' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m' + '&#46;' + 'sg';
 document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy21908 + '\'>');
 document.write(addy21908);
 document.write('<\/a>');
 //-->\n </script><script type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>');
 //-->
 </script>This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 document.write('</');
 document.write('span>');
 //-->
 </script></b></a></body></html>
```

how to get exact html input from above coding file? my expecting output like:

```
<a href="mailto:franchan@sph.com.sg"><b>franchan@sph.com.sg<span style='display: none;'>This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.</span></b></a>
```

currently i am and "SGML" reader, XML writer for convert well formed HTML

Regards, thanks in advance,

saran

Comment: I have to smile here. You obfuscate your email address to stop harvesters, and then post it in plaintext on one of the most harvested sites? Also you need to remove the <a href='mailto: from the page and add it to the script

Comment: To include html in xml, you need to wrap it in CDATA

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/daAym/)

```
<script type='text/javascript'><![CDATA[
window.onload=function() {
  var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
  var addy88710 = ['fr&#97;nch&#97;n','&#64;','sph','&#46;','c&#111;m','&#46;','sg']
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href=prefix + ':' + addy88710.join("");
  link.innerHTML=addy88710.join("");
  var span = document.getElementById("x");
  span.innerHTML="";
  span.appendChild(link);
}  
//]]></script>
 <span id="x">This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.<span>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to protect the emails, another simple solution is to create an image of the email on the fly and place it where the email text has to come, so it can't be caught by spammers. maybe alter the image so that ocr cant also read it easily.